# Can't replace the lines. Result - line of random symbols

Tags: c, string, replace

I have a task in my university that requires me to enter 2 lines and then replace them.

I'll be very thankful if u show me where did I make mistake. Sry for bad eng . _.

P.S.: the task requires also that I should write the program with couple of functions, not one. So, until I'd splitted my code to the functions, it was working as it needs to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int entstr1(char *, int long1);
int entstr2(char *, int long2);
int plustr(char*, char*, char*, int, int, int);
int i;
int longall, long1, long2;

int main(void) {
    char str1[7], str2[7], rstr[14];;

    

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    entstr1(str1, long1);
    entstr2(str2, long2);

    printf("%s", str1);
    printf("%s", str2);

    longall = long1 + long2;
    printf("\n%d", longall); // 

    plustr(str1, str2, rstr, longall, long1, long2);
    printf("\n\nResult line: %s", rstr);

    return 0;

}

int entstr1(char *str1, int long1) {
    
    printf("Enter 1 line: ");
    fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    long1 = strlen(str1);
    printf("\nLength of 1 line: %d\n", long1); //

    return 1;
}

int entstr2(char* str2, int long2) {

    printf("Enter 1 line: ");
    fgets(str2, sizeof str2, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    long2 = strlen(str2);
    printf("\nLength of 2 line: %d\n", long2); //

    return 1;
}

int plustr(char* str1, char* str2, char* rstr, int longall, int long1, int long2) {

    for (i = longall-1, long1; i > long2; i--, long1--) {
        rstr[i] = str1[long1];
    }
    for (i = long2; i != 0; i--) {
        rstr[i] = str2[i];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I've added a few test-commands to see if "longall" is have a bad value and so it is! IDK why it turns into 0, but the commands in entstr1 and entstr2 shows that long1 and long2 have right values, but then, it turns to 0 in a both variables when it goes to main function again)':

Comment: With `fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin)` the size of `str` is the size of the *pointer* variable `str1` itself. Which will be either `4` or `8` (depending on if you're on a 32- or 64-bit system).

Comment: Also remember that arguments are passed *by value*. Meaning the values at the call-site is *copied* into the functions local argument variable. Modifying that local variable will only modify the value of the local variable itself, not the original variable used in the call. So e.g. assigning to `long1` will not change it.

Comment: And furthermore, the C specification explicitly say that calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like `stdin`) leads to *undefined behavior*. Don't do that.

Comment: Oh and don't use global variables. Especially since you pass those variables to the functions anyway.

Comment: Lastly for how to solve your problem, you need to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. This will help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Also note that `entstr1()` and `entstr2()` are effectively identical, so they should be merged into one with suitable parameters.

Answer (score 0):

@Egor I wonder if my code is fully implement your idea. Can you check it is correct or not? Then, I explain it if needed. But as far as concerned you are quite good coder and no need any explanation whenever have seen this code.

Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 7

int entstr1(char *, int *long1);
int entstr2(char *, int *long2);
int plustr(char *, char *, char *, int, int, int);

int main(void) {
    char str1[MAX_LENGTH], str2[MAX_LENGTH], rstr[MAX_LENGTH * 2];
    int longall, long1, long2;

    entstr1(str1, &long1);
    entstr2(str2, &long2);

    printf("%s", str1);
    printf("%s", str2);

    longall = long1 + long2;
    printf("\n%d", longall);

    plustr(str1, str2, rstr, longall, long1, long2);
    printf("\n\nResult line: %s", rstr);

    return 0;
}

int entstr1(char *str1, int *long1) {
    printf("Enter 1 line: ");
    fgets(str1, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    *long1 = strlen(str1) - 1; // Adjust for the newline character
    printf("\nLength of 1 line: %d\n", *long1);

    return 1;
}

int entstr2(char *str2, int *long2) {
    printf("Enter 2 line: ");
    fgets(str2, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    *long2 = strlen(str2) - 1; // Adjust for the newline character
    printf("\nLength of 2 line: %d\n", *long2);

    return 1;
}

int plustr(char *str1, char *str2, char *rstr, int longall, int long1, int long2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < long1; i++) {
        rstr[i] = str1[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < long2; i++) {
        rstr[long1 + i] = str2[i];
    }

    rstr[longall] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the result string

    return 1;
}
```

This is my result:

[image]

Hope to be helpful.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thx you very much, have a good day (';

Comment: @EgorEgor I'd glad to see you happy. Why don't you upvote and tick me? ;-)

Comment: This is good answer what exactly worked.